# Username abuts reputation on question list, possibly new-nav only

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav, question-lists

I've not noticed it like this before, but the username is immediately followed by the reputation figure. An example from meta:

[image: Username abuts reputation]

Firefox 40.0, [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr)

On Stack Overflow I'm using the excellent new question-list thing where it is also present.

Following up on a comment from @FrédéricHamidi, I tried with Private Browsing, and there is a clear gap, so tagging as a possible issue with the new navigation.

Here's the same question with Private Browsing:

[image: User does not abut reputation in Private Browsing]

Comment: I'm not seeing this on my end (the gap is larger). Is your browser's zoom level lower than 100%?

Comment: I am noticing this also with Chrome 44 on windows 7

Comment: Could it be related to the new navigation UI then? (I'm not using it.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've just tried with various zoom levels, above and below 100%. They all look too close.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I didn't think that the new navigation affected meta. I'll try in a secret browser.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Good shot. In Private Browsing, there is a gap between the two.

Comment: I can see this is a change -- but is it a bug? Improvement?

Comment: @TZHX depends if it was intended or not. If not intended, it can still be a feature :-)

Comment: I tried poking around at the styles to see if there were any hints as to why this is, and I found that the cause is that when there is no gap, it is because the two HTML elements have no whitespace in-between them, and with the gap, there is whitespace. It's possible someone removed the space between the two elements, to try to make the code look a bit more compact, without realizing that it would affect the rendered spacing as well. But that's just guesswork at this point.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there is actually a style rule for `.newnav .reputation-score` giving it a 1px _larger_ `margin-left` value than the original style, however this style is being overriden by the original style anyways, and not even being applied.

Comment: @pnuts nice find. Status-completed it says. Or maybe it's just been like that since May and I've not noticed until now :-)

Comment: @pnuts No, it's not. And if it is intended, or deemed a temporary/permanent feature I have no problem with it (I'm not going to ask for it to be user-selectable, or complain that it hurts my eyes). Just noted it in case it is a symptom.

Comment: [tag:repro] Getting the same behaviour on Chrome 44 + Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: Getting the same behaviour on SO all browsers. Surely only on [tag:new-nav], InPrivate/LoggedOut is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, looks good. Thanks.